# How to get the image/attachments from one message and send them in a new message in a Slackbot using python?

Tags: python, bots, webclient, slack, slack-api

I'm making a slackbot using Python and the bolt and the Webclient api and I can't seem to find any documentation or answers on how to get the attachments (such as images) from one message and send them in a new message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to send attachment from one message to another, so I am assuming you are somehow(maybe by capturing 'message' event) loading the payload of original message in your code.

Whenever the message contains an attachment, there is **"files" attribute** added to it.

 https://api.slack.com/types/file 
You can fetch the details of files from this attribute and use it in your new message.

The main consideration is the **accessibility of the file**. If the message was a DM or similar scope, the file will not be accessible to rest of the users.

In case the file is not **publicly accessible** you can use following api to make it publicly accessible:
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL

Here is a sample json:

```
"file": {
        "id": "F0TD00400",
        "created": 1532293501,
        "timestamp": 1532293501,
        "name": "dramacat.gif",
        "title": "dramacat",
        "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
        "filetype": "gif",
        "pretty_type": "JPEG",
        "user": "U0L4B9NSU",
        "editable": false,
        "size": 43518,
        "mode": "hosted",
        "is_external": false,
        "external_type": "",
        "is_public": false,
        "public_url_shared": false,
        "display_as_bot": false,
    .
    .
    .

    }
```